# Layout algorithm for tree graph in Qt

Tags: qt, graph, layout, tree

I'm working on a family tree graph where the individual nodes are objects of a class derived from QGraphicsObject painted on the scene and I'm placing each node's parents centered above it, its spouse on the side and their children below them in a row with obvious node overlapping problems when new family members are added in specific positions. I was wondering whether there is a way in Qt to layout a tree like mine to minimize/avoid overlaps or whether I necessarily have to use external libraries (Graphviz etc..). Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a small example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: For example, if you have a couple with three children and you add a spouse to the child in the middle the row should expand horizontally to make room for the spouse; or again if you successfully add a spouse and you want to add parents for that spouse the tree should grow vertically.. and so on.